# make a title move from left to right in a neverending loop drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

What I want to do is at the top of my website I have a block and in that block the **title** of EMERGENCY messages can appear when there are emergency messages of course. 
This title is static at the moment but I want it to move from left to right in a neverending loop so the attention is drawn to it and users will click on it to open the emergency message.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow. I think you mean [marquee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element), but this is 2013 so that can't be right...

Comment: The person I'm making it for wants it, i'm not a fan of it either :p

Comment: lol, life would be so easy without clients ;)